# Python: Assign multiple system arguments in one simple line

Tags: python, arguments, variable-assignment

I've tried to find an answer to this, but nothing seems to fit the problem...

I want to in one simple line assign a `sys.argv` to a variable, in one simple line instead of doing the following:

```
var1 = sys.argv[1]
var2 = sys.argv[2]
var3 = sys.argv[3]
var4 = sys.argv[4]
var5 = sys.argv[5]
var6 = sys.argv[6]
etc...
```

is this possible?

Cheers,

MHibbin

Comment: Is it a set number of variables, or are you looking for a solution that will accept an arbitrary number of arguments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep:

```
var1,var2,var3,var4 = sys.argv[1:5]
```

This will only work if the iterable on the right side has 4 elements.  Python3.x extends this capability a bit:

```
var1,var2,var3,var4,*rest = sys.argv[1:]
```

In this variation, you unpack the first 4 elements of `sys.argv[1:]` into variables and the rest of `sys.argv` gets put into the list `rest`.

For commandline parsing, I would definitely recommend `argparse`.  It ships with python2.7, and can easily be installed for older versions of python.

Comment: That's great thanks! Sadly I am stuck with 2.7 (for the rest list), however I will look at the argparse module. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You can use this syntax:

```
var1, var2, var3 = sys.argv[1:]
```

Note that the number of variables must match the length of the list. Usually, it's better to use the [getopt module](http://docs.python.org/library/getopt.html).